# Does Leaflet.js uses WebGL for drawing on HTML5 canvas?

Tags: leaflet

If someone could explain how does the Leaflet.js library draws object (and map layers) on HTML5 canvas? Does it uses WebGL and its GPU accelerated usage of physics and image processing in any way?

Answer (score 4):

The [Leaflet.js](http://leafletjs.com/) project is open source. Just go to its [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet) and poke around. You'll quickly find that there is no WebGL component. However it does make use of [hardware-accelerated CSS3](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/optimization-and-performance/), which can be disabled globally: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#global

Answer (score 4):

While it isn't baked into leaflet, there is: https://github.com/robertleeplummerjr/Leaflet.glify which is based off of http://bl.ocks.org/Sumbera/c6fed35c377a46ff74c3

The demo loads 86,000 points and all the polygons behind them in about 0.06 seconds.  If you position the map away from the the points and then pull them back into view you'll see what I mean.